# Spurious solutions in a first order system

Tags: dynamical-systems, change-of-variable

The problem is that after a seemingly trivial change of coordinates I get spurious solutions and I can't explain why.

The ODE is
\begin{equation}
\ddot x+a\dot x(x^2+\dot x^2-1)+x=0
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to the first-order system
\begin{cases}
\dot x=y \\
\dot y=-x-ay(x^2+y^2-1)
\end{cases}

By taking the polar coordinates, I get the equations
\begin{cases}
\dot r\cos\theta-r\dot{\theta}\sin\theta=r\sin\theta \\
\dot r\sin\theta+r\dot{\theta}\cos\theta=-r\cos\theta-ar\sin\theta(r^2-1)
\end{cases}

Then, by equating the coefficients of the sines and the cosines, I get at once both these equations for $\dot r$

\begin{equation}
\dot r=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot r=-ar(r^2-1)
\end{equation}

I have a feeling that I should discard $\dot r=0$, but I'm not able to provide an explanation for this. Why should I discard that equation and the solutions it brings?

Comment: Why would you equate the coefficients of $\sin$ and $\cos$. That step does not make sense to me. Also, use `\cos` and `\sin` in your expressions

Comment: Because on both sides of those equations I have power series, which are equal iff their coefficients are equal.

Comment: But you have also the unknown function $\dot θ$ that could completely change the series expansions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than comparing coefficients that are not constant, consider this as a linear system in $\dot r$, $r\dot θ$,
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{\cosθ&-\sinθ\\\sinθ&\cosθ}\pmatrix{\dot r\\r\dot θ}
=\pmatrix{r\sinθ\\-r\cosθ+ar(r^2-1)\sinθ}
\end{align}
As the matrix is a rotation, you can solve this by multiplying with the transpose matrix.

---

You could of course also use that
$$
r\dot r=y\dot y+x\dot x=\dot x(\ddot x+x)=-a\dot x^2(r^2-1)
\\\implies
\dot r=a(1-r^2)r\sin^2θ
$$
and
$$
r^2\dot θ=x\dot y-y\dot x=-r^2+x(\ddot x+x)=-r^2-ax\dot x(r^2-1)
\\\implies \dot θ=-1+a(1-r^2)\sinθ\cosθ
$$

Comment: Just to clarify what @LutzLehmann is saying, you multiply **on the left** both sides of the equation with the inverse of the rotation matrix

Answer (score 0):

From

\begin{cases}
\dot x=y \\
\dot y=-x-ay(x^2+y^2-1)
\end{cases}

multiplying the first equation by $x$, the second by $y$ and adding both we have

$$
\frac 12\left(x^2+y^2\right)'=-a y^2(x^2+y^2-1)
$$

or in polar coordinates

$$
r\dot r = r^2(1-r^2)a\sin^2\theta
$$

or

$$
\dot r = r(1-r^2)a\sin^2\theta
$$

etc.